# how to know elementRef who generates event

Tags: angular, angular5, elementref

I have same listener for different inputs.

When listener is fired, I can't get who generates the event.

```
<form #f="ngForm">
<mat-card-content>
  <mat-input-container>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="id" name="id" placeholder="ID" (ngModelChange)="inputChanged()" />
  </mat-input-container>
  <mat-input-container>
    <input matInput [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" placeholder="NAME" (ngModelChange)="inputChanged()" />
  </mat-input-container>
</mat-card-content>
</form>

//ts

inputChanged():void{
  //how to know who generates
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just do that:

```
(ngModelChange)="inputChanged('one')"

inputChanged(name: string):void{
  console.log(name);
}
```

And put some logic inside `inputChanged`

Answer (score 0):

You can use two different functions and if they need to do same thing, then they can call a shared function later.

```
<input matInput [(ngModel)]="id" name="id" placeholder="ID" (ngModelChange)="onIdChange($event)"/>

<input matInput [(ngModel)]="name" name="name" placeholder="NAME" (ngModelChange)="onNameChange($event)" />
```

In `component.ts`

```
onIdChange(event) {
   // some logic
}

onNameChange(event) {
   // some logic
}
```